# Numbers separated by hyphen getting reversed in arabic string

Tags: android, bidi

My string looks like this "تغطية مباشرة.. ريال مدريد 2-0 مانشستر يونايتد", When I setText in a textview the numbers are getting reversed i.e(0-2 becomes 2-0).
I have tried setting text direction but it wasn't helpful.

Any ideas how to avoid the reversal?

Comment: You will need to set an explicit RTL direction on the text and LTR on the numbers. It is probably using a bidi algorithm to guess directionality.

Comment: Have you set _RTL_ direction ?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts okay I can check bidi, Piyush yes already tried it. Also this issue occurs only on Samsung devices.

Comment: That strongly suggests that it the bidi algorithm in Samsung that is the problem, so that's why you'll need to be specifc.

Comment: right, so using bidi algorithm I have to set rtl on text & ltr on numbers?another observation is that numbers like '12345' are rendered properly its only the case of hyphen(-) that reverses.

Comment: if you are using left or right for text alignment, so change left to start and right to end.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your activity `onCreate` method :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: this does not helps.

Comment: Can you copy your xml file please ?